# Creating a multivariate greek function?

Tags: greek

For instance, I know `\phi` gives me the lower case greek letter phi, but how would I go about creating something like: phi(x,t), in latex?

I tried `\phi(x,t)` and `\phi{x,t}`, but I got an error when I tried to compile my code into a pdf.

Comment: You have to write `$\phi(x,t)$` or `$\phi\{x,t\}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to just display the "function" as text within your LaTeX document?  If so, then just wrap your command with the math environment $.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\phi(x,t)$

\end{document}
```

[image: Phi]